# QTP/VBA - Difference between VBA IE automation and testing tool QTP

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, qtp

Similar to QTP using VBA I'm able to navigate through the webpages

(Internet explorer) and  able to do all the actions.

If everything is possible with VBA IE ,why there is a need to use QTP.

Please help me to understand the difference between these two

Comment: VBA IE automation isn't an automatic testing tool but QTP is. They really aren't comparable since they target different problem domains, hence your question seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 3):

I had come up with a framework myself by using pure VBScript & IE COM (`InternetExplorer.Application`) for web application automation on IE browser wihtout using QTP.

But with VBscript, you can only automate IE. You can not run the same script on FF & Chrome.

QTP is an IDE & it comes with a datatable for storing the data, reporting engine, `Recovery scenarios` for error handling, Object repository for keeping the test objects information completely away from the test script. QTP can also be used to automate desktop applications, java, siebel, mainframe applications etc.

If your requirement is to automate IE only, QTP will be helpful to increase your productivity from writing tons of code as it has many utility inbuilt functions.

Comment: Thanks Vinoth..anyway everything can be achievable using VBA IE also similar to QTP right

Comment: If your requirement is to automate IE only, then you can do using VBScript.  You do not need QTP.